# Max width in media query does nothing

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my website design responsive.

So far, I've got the following rules:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    /* styles for screen width 1000px and wider */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px)and (max-width: 800px) {
    /* styles for screen width between 500px and 800px */
}
```

For some reason, the last media query doesn't work. In fact, it completely strips all styles from every element on the page.

I've been looking around and I can't find any hint as to why this is or what I'm doing wrong...

I feel like I'm missing a concept or something... Everyone's talking to me about percentages, and while I'm taking that on board, I'm not seeing how it relates to the media queries not applying the style rules.

Can anyone provide any clarity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you add a space before the last `and`? Browsers and I think the spec are whitespace-sensitive (if it's a word). Or what if you put the second MQ before the current first one?

Comment: What you have here is syntactically correct - this may be any number of issues, from your actual CSS rules within the media query not being specific enough, to it being a browser issue, if you're looking at IE. Could you provide us with either a stronger example, a JSFiddle, or simply more information and context?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a closing comment tag.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    /* styles for screen width 1000px and wider */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px)and (max-width: 800px) {
    /* styles for screen width between 500px and 800px */
}
```

Nothing else wrong here.

Comment: that's just a typo in what I posted for the question

Comment: @Ortund Well, no one is unable to help you if you don't post your full code.

Comment: My full code's about 200 lines long. I seriously doubt you or anyone else would be willing to go through all of it anyway

Comment: Then debug it. Your problem could be anywhere. Delete cache, try something simple.